# Why does assigning to one element of a list result in two mutations?

Tags: python, list, indices, mutation

This code block is giving me unexpected results, and I am not sure why:

```
grid = [[0] * cols] * rows
grid[0][1] = 1
print(grid) # [[0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

I expected the grid to be [[0, 1], [0, 0]], not [[0, 1], [0, 1]]. What causes grid[1][1] to be mutated as well?

Thank you.

Comment: There is a *single mutation* here. You have *one* list in `grid` repeated `row` number of times. Every row **is the exact same list object**

Comment: `grid = [[0] * cols] * rows` This creates many references to _the same inner list object_.

Comment: The answer, by the way, is to do `[[0] * cols for _ in rows]`.